# how to calculate average when sum in multi array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have already function that SUM sub arrays which has matches keys   like this

```
 $totals = array();
 $count_loops = 0 ; 
    // First get our totals.
        foreach ($average as $subKey => $subArray) {
            foreach ($subArray as $k => $v) {
                // Add the column to our total.
                $totals[$k] = isset($totals[$k] ) ? $totals[$k] + $v / $count_loops : $v;
            }
        }
```

and return total array like this

```
Array
(
    [john_total] => 519.44
    [adam_total] => 1664.64
    [sara_total] => 1237.53
}
```

but i want to return average after sum bu divide sum number with count loops,but it return wrong average..if i delete this code `/ $count_loops` 
it sum good..so how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Think you can use : [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-sum.php) and [count](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.count.php) function in PHP :

```
$totals = array();
 $count_loops = 0 ; 
    // First get our totals.
        foreach ($average as $subKey => $subArray) {
            $totals[$k] = array_sum($subArray) / count($subArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `array_sum` and `count`

> array_sum will give you sum of total result.
>
> and count will give you total number of element.
>
> and average is A calculated "central" value of a set of numbers.

so

```
$average = array_sum($array) / count($array);
```

Comment: i want it to return like this array Array
(
    [john_total] => 519.44
    [adam_total] => 1664.64
    [sara_total] => 1237.53
}

Comment: but with average calculation

Comment: i want to count every value indvidually jon may be repeated 3 times but sara may be 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful of the calculation which is going to happen at this point of your code.

```
$totals[$k] = isset($totals[$k] ) ? $totals[$k] + $v / $count_loops : $v;
```

I'd rather you have it as

```
$totals[$k] = isset($totals[$k] ) ? ( $totals[$k] + $v ) / $count_loops : $v;
```

> ( 5 + 2.5 ) / 2 => 7.5 / 2 = 3.75
>
> 5 + ( 2.5 / 2 ) => 5 + 1.25 = 6.25

Those calculations are same figures but dependent on operator precedence. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: this Array
(
    [john_total] => 519.44
    [adam_total] => 1664.64
    [sara_total] => 1237.53
}

Comment: but with divde by 2..number 2 is the number of duplicated for jon or sara or anyone..because average is the total / count numbers

Comment: so jon will be 259.72

Comment: Did you take a look firstly at operator precedence to understand how that works? You might see your code working as A while it is actually doing a B. Code output gives your exactly what you have written. Make amends too your function and see if it resolves then we continue from there.

Comment: the problem with  $count_loops ..it must count all repeated values and then dived but this is not gonna happen because the number start with number 1 in he first loop so he dived with wrong number

Comment: How do you get your `$count_loops`? If you initialize it as `$count_loops = 0 ;` Don't you think you should increment the value according to the number of repeated value, something like `$count_loops++;` in your function so it can give an accurate division value?